# How to add key value pair in an JSON dynamically using Lodash or JS in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have JSON like this:

```
let json = {
   data:[
     {value1: 1},
     {Value2: 2}
   ]
}

maths:100
science:100
```

I need to add these two key value pairs to the json:

```
let json = {
      data:[
        {value1:1},
        {Value2:2}
      ],
      maths:100,
      science:100
}
```

Comment: Please note that you do not have any JSON in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
let json = {
   data:[{value1:1},{Value2:2}]
}
console.log({...json, maths: 100, science: 100})
```

Comment: @Dhanush, not sure why you have accepted this answer, as in your question you have how to add key values dynamically in existing JSON, not like printing simply on console..?

Comment: After receiving a response from the api..i am going to dispatch it into the state, while dispatching I will use your method. Anyway, those two values that I am adding are not dynamic, it is a hardcoded one. so no problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting this output

```
{"data":[{"value1":1},{"Value2":2}],"maths":100,"science":100}
```

You can check the following code

```
let json = {
    "data":[
        {
        "value1":1
        },{
        "Value2":2
        }
    ]
}

function pushToAry(name, val) {
   var obj = {};
   json[name] = val;
}

pushToAry("maths", 100);
pushToAry("science", 100);
console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Else, If you are expecting the below output

```
{"data":[{"value1":1},{"Value2":2},{"maths":100},{"science":100}]}
```

You can check the following code

```
let json = {
   "data":[
       {
          "value1":1
       },{
          "Value2":2
       }
   ]
}

function pushToAry(name, val) {
   var obj = {};
   obj[name] = val;
   json["data"].push(obj);
}

pushToAry("maths", 100);
pushToAry("science", 100);
console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Comment: @Dhanush, no problem, my solution was based on your question asked and there since it was not mentioned that it is hard-corded values, anyways glad to know m able to help you in some way:)